# how to get string array values from a stream?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, web

I'm trying to return a string array from the server-side and retrieve it from the client-side.this is how my server-side looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public string[] GetFileNameList()
{
    //get file names from the Directory
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ndmendis\Desktop\files\in", "*.txt");
    return files;
}
```

this is how my client-side looks like:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:59831/Home/GetFileNameList/");
    request.ContentType = "application/text";
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    //request.ContentLength = 0;
    request.Method = "GET";

    var response = request.GetResponse();
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    String[] str = responseFromServer.Cast<string>().Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

From the client-side, i'm trying to the access the server over http, and it works. It goes to my server-side. And the server-side is returning the string array perfectly. 
But the issue is I'm not getting the proper content of that string array(My **'responseFromServer'** variables value is string[]). **'responseFromServer'** variable should contain the values i'm passing. Can someone please address the issue i'm having? thank you!

Apparently in the response variable there is a tag called segment. All the values(values that i'm sending from the server) are inside it but it seems that my stream doesn't contain those values...
[image]

Comment: what do you get at `responseFromServer`?

Comment: I'm getting the response as a stream and i'm converting it to a string using streamreader...

Comment: @Dayan I guess, he is asking about the contents of this string at a runtime.

Comment: yes.. i'm not getting the proper response

Comment: what are you getting from the streamreader?

Comment: inside the stream, there is a tag call segment, inside that i'm getting those values... but i'm not really sure how to get them into a string[]

Comment: The segments you are seeing are the different parts from the URL you are requesting. Not the filenames inside the folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cant comment (not enough reputation).
But try the following Read the entire response stream as a byte array and then deseriaze it (Using .Net Serialization classes) into a string array (object).

EDIT: 
I built this example on the default WebApi Values Controller, which incidentally also returns an array of strings.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var url = "http://localhost:14596/api/values";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
            byte[] result = client.DownloadData(url);
            // now use a JSON parser to parse the resulting string back to some CLR object
            string[] resultArr = parse(result);

        }
    }

    public static string[] parse(byte[] json)
    {
         string jsonStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(jsonStr);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not really sure how to do it... can you give me an example

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems like you are using ASP.NET WebAPI to send the response. And from the code you posted it seems like the web api is working correctly.

The problem is most likely on the `Content-Type`.

Information in HTTP protocol is always sent using binary information. Since binary information can be interpreted in many different ways, the standard provides for a `Content-Type` header so that a connecting client can know the format is the server sending the data in.

In the particular case of ASP.NET WebAPI, the default configuration is to use XML. So while your API method returns a string, WebAPI will silently pack it as an XML file, and send that instead. If you have configured another MediaTypeFormatter, that's the format you will receive.

So when you get your result it is in that format. It might be possible to convert that format to a string (which you definitely can do if it is XML), but trying to use `Cast<string>` on it will never turn it into an array of strings. It will turn it into an array of Chars represented as strings (which is my guess of what you are seeing).

If you want to read XML and deserialize it into an array of `strings[]` you would need code similar to this one:

```
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(responseFromServer))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
        str = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as string[];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The fact that you set the request content-type to application/text has no bearing on what the API will send you back. What the `content-type` in the request indicates is the format the client used in the request to the server.

If you wanted to indicate which format you would like your answer to be, take a look at the `Accept` header, but be mindful that asking for an `application/text` will not work in a default WebAPI configuration (and furthermore it wouldn't have much sense when you tried to deserialize it).

Comment: @dayan Could you post the content of the responseFromServer string in your question?

Comment: this is what's inside my responseFromServer  variable 'System.String[]'...nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no idea how many lines are going to be in your server side ,you can't create a `string[]` of the correct size up front.

Instead, you could start with a collection of strings:

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

Change your loop to:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(line);
    }
}
```

And then ask for a string array from your list:

```
string[] result = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Apparently my Stream is null, therefore  list value is null... i have edited my question with a screenshot... it explains why(stream is null, but the response variable contains the values)